# ModelForm with ForeignKey in inherited Model

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-forms

The Model:

```
class Human(models.Model):
  UNIQUE = models.CharField(max_length=10)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  father = models.ForeignKey('Human', null=True, blank=True)
  mother = models.ForeignKey('Human', null=True, blank=True)

class Person(Human):
  email = models.EmailField()
```

And now, i'm trying to make ModelForm:

```
class PersonForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Person
    fields = ('UNIQUE','name','email')
```

Till this - works perfect.

And now I want to add two fields: father and mother

If Person already has father (and/or mother) - just show name. If not - show field (or both fields), where user has to type UNIQUE.

I stack on just adding field: I try to add father mother into Class Meta Fields:

```
class PersonForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Person
    fields = ('UNIQUE','name', 'email', 'father', 'mother')
```

the error says:

```
Exception Type: AttributeError 
Exception Value: 'Person' object has no attribute 'father_id'
```

which is not true, because it has this attribute (inherited from human)....any hints?

Most of solutions points into choiceview, but I don't want to show possibilities - just enter UNIQUE, if it is in base - show, if not - do nothing

**edited**

because the discussion goes wrong way - the model Human and model Person is surely good - in the admin everything works properly - but I create the interface for entering data (i don't want to select father/mother from other possibilities like in admin module)

**edited2**
The very important modification:

```
  father = models.ForeignKey('Human', related_name="father", null=True, blank=True)
  mother = models.ForeignKey('Human', related_name="mother", null=True, blank=True)
```

The error disappears, and in form appears the id of mother/father - it is very close to change it into UNIQUE

Comment: `father = models.ForeignKey, null=True, blank=True)` - very strange line. Is it exact code?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - of course not...

Comment: Why are you doing `model = Person` in `ModelForm` and not `model = Human`? Error tell exactly, what happens: Person model doesn't have `father` field

Comment: this is not the real code and full with mistakes. Would you post the real code?

Comment: Person also doesn't have name and UNIQUE

Comment: obayhan - it is real code, where you see mistakes? (only few wrong indents fixed now)

Comment: stalk - because i need to edit Person, not Human - Person is Human with email

Comment: Person has UNIQUE, name, father and mother because it inherits from Human. I've had this problem few times. I hope I can come back with solution.

Comment: I think that Django tries to find the id field of the class `Human` by adding `_id` to the attribute name. What happens if you put `self` instead of `Human` in the ForeignKey fields?

Comment: Maybe you should put `db_column='whateveryouridis'` into the fields `father` and `mother`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in related_names which was the same as field name -this leads to errors..

This is correct answer:
     father = models.ForeignKey('Human', related_name="fathers_children", null=True, blank=True)
     mother = models.ForeignKey('Human', related_name="mothers_children", null=True, blank=True)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid extended discussion in comments I put here a possible answer.
Do you have both tables `person` and `human` in the database?
The class `Person` inherits from `Human` and thus the recursive relations. If the table `human` is not in the database, then all the tries of the class `Person` to establish the relations are futile.

EDIT:

So let's summarize it, since it seems that the related names were causing the problem.
When creating multiple foreign keys from one model to another (or to itself as recursive relation) you need to specify different related names. If not specified, Django tries to create related name by appending `_set` to the model name.
In your case it would be something like `person.human_set.all()` (`person` being instance of the class `Person`). And here it can't be distinguished between father and mother.
There is also a possibility to disable the backward relation by declaring the related name as `+`:
`related_name='+'`

Comment: yes of course both are in database. Person has email and human_ptr_id which is pointer to the human id.

Comment: Where does `human_ptr_id` comes from? The error message says that `Person` has no attribute `father_id`. Django appends `_id` to find the primary key of the related model. The table `human` must have something like a primary key. What is the name of this column in the database?

Comment: The django itself creates the database. I modify nothing in database. The primary key in human is of course id.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your case, but I couldn't reproduce the error so far. As I see `human_ptr` and `human_ptr_id` are automatically created. The attributes `father_id` and `mother_id` are also created. But how did you achieve to sync your models. I get error because `Human` is not yet created, because `Person` is declared first. There is also an error because of the related names. Having two foreign keys to the same model leads to a conflict with the related names, therefore you should specify them explicitly.

Comment: Which version of Django do you use?

Comment: Damn it, your right! the related_names are very important! I thought that it's enough to has different names, so i remove the related_names , but it was very stupid!